# Google Form on submit replace the blank values to Zero

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

My code is not working!

I want to

1. replace the blank values to number 0 from spreadsheet
2. from column range F to AN for the recent row
3. on the form submit trigger.

I am trying to write a function in Code.gs as below -

```
function formSubmit() {

  var form = FormApp.openById("my Form Id");
  var formItems = form.getItems();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('F:AN'); // for last row/current row

  range.forEach (function (row) {
     row.forEach ( function (cell) {
        if (isBlank()) { 
          cell.setValue(0);
        }
     });
   }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain about the detail information of `My code is not working!`?

Comment: ``Spreadsheet`` is different from `Form`. Is the script bound to spreadsheet or form. Also `getRange()` returns a `range` class object. It is not a array. To get values, use `range.getValues()` and there are multiple other errors. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for **Codelabs** to get started  with apps script and other resources.

Answer (score 0):

In your form make these fields required. This will prevent users from leaving the fields blank.